# Chartkick gem error on running redmine server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, chartkick

Hopefully somebody can be of help to me here.

I´m using linux, ruby version 1.8.7 and rails version 3.2.21 and redmine version 2.6.2

I´m dealing with an error when trying to install/run chartkick

before installing i´ve shut down redmine server and

I followed these steps to install:

in Gemfile put the line

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

an executed the follwing comand to install this gem:

```
bundle install --without production
```

at first time, it seems that installed with sucess cause no error is informed.

but when i run up the redmine server it shows me the error..

see stacktrace below:

```
# /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.10.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in 'require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chartkick-1.4.2/lib/chartkick.rb:20: odd number list for Hash (Syntax Error)
    {name: name, data: data.map { |k, v| [k[1], v] }}
              ^  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chartkick-1.4.2/lib/chartkick.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
    {name: name, data: data.map { |k, v| [k[1], v] }}
              ^  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chartkick-1.4.2/lib/chartkick.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
    {name: name, data: data.map { |k, v| [k[1], v] }}
                          ^  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chartkick-1.4.2/lib/chartkick.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chartkick-1.4.2/lib/chartkick.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

Please, Any ideas what whould i do to solve this problem ? what am i doing wrong ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear error:

You'v bundled gem written with ruby 1.9 hash syntax.

`In version 1.9 Ruby introduced new syntax for hash literals whose keys are symbols. Hashes use the "hash rocket" operator to separate the key and the value`

According to provided setup you can safely upgrade your ruby from 1.8 to at least 1.9.3[-p551]

Check [RBenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io) to install certain version of Ruby.